GTM249 Fourier Analysis - Problem 7.1.11
Consider the function
$$u(x)=\begin{cases}
\log 1/|x|, &|x|<1/e\\
1, &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Show that this function is an $A_1$ weight. Given a ball $B(x_0,R)$, the hint on the book suggests to consider two different cases: $|x_0|<3R$ or $|x_0|\geq 3R$. I tried to do some analysis in both cases, but difficulties arises because this function is defined piecewise. I hope someone can give me more hints on this problem.

What is an $A_1$ weight ?
